Most constraining constraint CP-SAT
I am using CP-SAT to minimize a problem similar to Flexible Job Shop Scheduling (https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/flexible_job_shop_sat.py), with a minimization objective.
I was wondering if OR-tools provided feedback on 'most constraining constraint'. For example;
Minimize 3x + 5y --> assuming integers for x and y
Constraint1: x, y ≥ 1
Constraint2: x + y ≥ 3
Constraint3: x, y nonnegative
Then constraint1 makes it so that the minimal value is 8. However, by constraint2, the minimum value would be 11. Would the CP-SAT model be able to report that this constraint would yield the most objective value improvement if relaxed?

In practice, you might want to consider relaxing constraints without removing them (e.g., change the right hand side of constraint2 from 3 to 2). In LP models, you can get at this through dual values ("shadow prices"). In MIP and CP-SAT models, I think you are limited to trial and error.

You could do this inside one model.
$$\begin{aligned}
\min\> & 3x+5y \\
& \delta_1 = 1 \implies x \ge 1 \\
& \delta_1 = 1 \implies y \ge 1 \\
& \delta_2 = 1 \implies x+y \ge 3 \\
& \delta_3 = 1 \implies x \ge 0 \\
& \delta_3 = 1 \implies y \ge 0 \\
& \sum_k \delta_k = 2 \\
& \delta_k \in \{0,1\}
\end{aligned}$$
The equations to relax are identified by $\delta_k=0$ in the solution.

This may make sense in a linear problem with  the LP relaxation, but this makes no sense in general with a CP-SAT problem, in particular scheduling.
The only option would be remove the constraint, and reoptimize.

For my case, it could be useful to see which machinery constraints the eventual output the most. For a small number of machines, this is easy to see visually, but becomes complex with many machines. Thanks for the insight.
